# Error during build process: "error: cannot find symbol method createSingle(<anonymous Callable<Scenario>>)"

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

I am getting the following error when compiling:

```
error: cannot find symbol method createSingle(<anonymous Callable<Scenario>>)
```

It looks to be happening in the Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Scenario WHERE id=:scenarioId")
Single<Scenario> getScenario (long scenarioId);
```

The id field in Scenario is the primary key and is unique:

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Scenario WHERE id=:scenarioId")
Maybe<Scenario> getScenario (long scenarioId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Query,because your query may be return more than 1 results.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Scenario WHERE id=:scenarioId")
Single<List<Scenario>> getScenario (long scenarioId);
```

Comment: Is that required? The id field in Scenario is the primary key, auto generated, and is unique [@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)].